# When Ron broke his wand, why didn't he apply for Hogwarts financial aid?

Tags: harry-potter, economics

We know, from Book Six, that Hogwarts has a financial aid for students in need. It's supposed to cover all expenses regarding materials and school supplies, so it certainly covers wands. So why didn't Ron simply apply for this fund when he broke his wand in Book Two, since his family could not afford a new one?

Seems absurd that no teacher would notice that Ron had a broken wand and inform him there's a school fund. Plot hole?

Obs.: Even if Ron *could* afford a new wand, one could ask how we would purchase it (you must experiment personally to find a wand that chooses you). It turns out that there's a local branch of Ollivander in Hogsmeade. I'm sure that, under those circumstances, a second-year student like Ron would be allowed to visit Hogsmeade to purchase a new wand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that part of the Weasley's general characterization is that even though they're poor, they're proud - and refuse to accept charity of any kind. I don't really have any citations for that though (but I could give you some of the same attitude in Terry Pratchett :))

Comment: Pride.  Pure and simple; like many who don't have much money, but manage to get along, he would rather find a way to make do than take a handout, much less ASK for a handout.  The only reason the Twins took the money from Harry was feeling guilty and said "“Look,” he said flatly, “take it, or I’ll hex you. I know some good ones now. Just do me one favor, okay? Buy Ron some different dress robes and say they’re from you.”" -- I have no canon backup, tho, so it's just a comment.

Comment: See the related question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11853 Why didn't Harry Potter anonymously give money to Ron, at least for important stuff like a non-broken wand?

Answer (score 25):

As Mrs Weasley says: "We'll manage."

> ‘That lot won’t come cheap,’ said George, with a quick look at his parents. ‘Lockhart’s books are really expensive ...’
>   ‘Well, we’ll manage,’ said Mrs Weasley, but she looked worried.
>   <sub>*Chamber of Secrets* - page 38 - Bloomsbury - chapter 4, *At Flourish and Blotts*</sub>

I think the Weasleys would expend every single option imaginable before applying for charity on Ron's behalf, and even then I don't think they would do it. Mr Weasley actually doesn't have a bad job; I think he gets paid adequately for his work as a government employee. However, with such a big family, a Galleon just doesn't stretch as far as it might elsewhere. The Weasleys just do *not* seem the type to ask for charity, IMO.

Furthermore, Ron, after receiving his Howler, knew better than to ask for a new wand:

> ‘Oh yeah, and get another Howler back,’ said Ron, stuffing the now hissing wand into his bag. *‘It’s your own fault your wand got snapped* –’
>   <sub>*Chamber of Secrets* - page 74 - Bloomsbury - chapter 6, *Gilderoy Lockhart*</sub>

I don't think he dared to ask for a new wand. And if he didn't tell his parents his wand was broken, and apparently none of the Hogwarts staff did either, then I think the Weasleys might plausibly have not known Ron needed a new wand. He didn't go home for the Christmas holidays, so he could have managed to hide the status of his wand from his parents until the summer holidays.

There are two possible exceptions to this: One, it's possible Ron went home for the Easter holiday (I personally don't remember that he did, but I could be wrong), and 2) when Molly and Arthur Weasley came up to Hogwarts after Ginny was rescued from the Chamber of Secrets, perhaps they noticed Ron's broken wand, or Ron told them about it due to the backfiring memory charm incident with Gilderoy Lockhart.

J.K. Rowling doesn't tell us *why* the Hogwarts staff didn't notify the Weasleys about Ron's wand, so there's no way to answer this part of your question definitively. :)

Comment: The fact that Ron spent the _entire year_ with a broken wand pretty much means that the Weasleys tried every option without being able to "manage it" and yet they still didn't apply for financial aid. I think it's possible that Ron didn't say anything to his parents...but then how come no teacher ever told him he needed to buy a new wand?

Comment: I don't think we can assume. Ron, after receiving his Howler, knew better than to ask for a new wand: *‘Oh yeah, and get another Howler back,’ said Ron, stuffing the now hissing wand into his bag. ‘It’s your own fault your wand got snapped –’* I don't think he asked for a wand. And if he didn't tell his parents, and apparently none of the staff did either, then I think the Weasleys might not have known Ron needed a new wand. He didn't go home for Christmas. The Weasleys just are *not* the charity type, IMO. JKR doesn't tell us why staff didn't notify the Weasleys about Ron's wand. :)

Comment: Add that comment with the quote to the answer

Comment: @DVK -- Have added the comment and quote to the answer. :)