# In The Chamber of Secrets, why did the Weasleys have to buy so many books, ie 5 sets of Lockharts books?

Tags: harry-potter

In the beginning of *Chamber of Secrets,* the Weasleys and Harry get their book lists which have all the Lockhart books and one of the twins remarks that 5 sets of Lockhart's books won't come cheap. Molly also mentions that they'll be able to get a lot of Ginnys books secondhand.

But why wouldn't Ginny just use Ron's books from the previous year?

And as for the Lockhart books, there's only one teacher, Lockhart, so really they'd need two sets max, as Fred and George would need a set each being in the same class, but couldn't the books get passed around between the other siblings?

I know it seems trivial, but for a poor family you think they would be a bit thriftier about the books.

On another note, Dumbledore mentions to Tom Riddle, in his memory in *The Half Blood Prince*, that Hogwarts has a fund for those who can't afford stuff. Did the Weasleys ever get anything from that fund?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You might want to ask that second Question as a second question

Comment: Yeah, the sponsorship question deserves to be a separate question in itself.

Comment: Second part should be split out into its own post (although [a similar question has already been asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26354/3567)). I feel like the first part is also a dupe, although I'm having trouble finding it right now.

Comment: It's rather unlikely that another teacher (Quirrell) wouldn't have used Lockhart's books as teaching material.

Comment: To rake in the galleons my friend ;)

Answer (score 9):

> But why wouldn't Ginny just use Ron's books from the previous year?

If the prescribed books are the same for the previous year (i.e. when Ron was in the first year), then Ginny might've used Ron's books. However, that might not be the same. So, that was the reason Ginny had to buy those books.

Prescribed books sometimes remain the same throughout the years, and sometimes change. And that list for each subject is generally given by the respective Professors before it is compiled and mailed to students.  (And it's not tough to bet that the list was compiled by Lockhart for that year!)

(I partially agree with your second point about the twins sharing the books, as they're in the same year.)

But, if the twins take different courses, then they can't share books between them. An optimized option would be to buy the books of their common classes and sharing them and buy the other books separately each.

Comment: The second point is supposed to be the other way around, I believe (i.e. that the twins will need two sets of books, as they're in the same year, but they can share these two with all the other brothers, who will have classes at different times). Of course they will not necessarily share all the same classes (they're in third year at this point, which means electives), though they might since they are very similar (even in personality).

Comment: This is likely the intended reason as Hogwarts would be equivalent to a private school, the only large scale one for the entire UK.  As such, they likely have high standards that they try to live up to concerning magical theory and application, so they would want their textbooks to be updated each year with the newest information possible.  This is similar to many systems in place in the Muggle world where new textbooks editions are put out quite often in certain fields and not so much in others.

Answer (score 1):

The real reason is that Lockheart has a huge ego, and listed *all* of his books as required textbooks so that people would be forced to buy them.

Since nobody prior to that had bothered to buy any, the Weasleys (and every other student) were forced to buy a full set for each child.  That is, they were never prescribed texts before, or after, that year.

As it happened, most of Lockheart's books were exaggerated or downright fictional, as his abilities as a wizard were somewhat lacking.  This can be seen in the ease with which Snape wins their duel.

Comment: No, no, Lockart just wanted to make Snape look good ;) Jokes aside, he could be quite possibly the deadliest duelist, if he were to use *obliviate*. You can't cast spells that you cannot remember

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there is a good chance that the siblings COULD have shared copies of Lockheart's books (or Ron share Harry's). However, there was also a high chance that they would all need the same book at the same time, especially since Lockheart was far more likely to prepare his lessons for several years from the same book at the same time (since he required each of the years to HAVE all of the books) rather than going through the trouble of creating 7 completely different lesson plans. Rather than have to deal with buying more of the books and sending them to the kids later (if they ever admitted that they we, it seems that Molly was willing to put up with the extra cost up front.

Answer (score -4):

Probably because every girl and woman was smitten with Lockhart. Molly was visibly just as smitten with Lockhart as every other female was.